# How to remove one element (other type) list and add adapter ...using Json Url

Tags: android, json

How to remove one element (other type) list and add adapter ...Using Json [Url](http://%20http://beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/VJLp4IzDX)

And Json Response is

```
[{"ProdType":"Gas","uId":11000},{"ProdType":"Petrol","uId":11001},{"ProdType":"Diesel","uId":11002},{"ProdType":"other type","uId":11003},{"ProdType":"special items","uId":11006}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();     
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray)jsonObject; 
int len = jsonArray.length();
if (jsonArray != null) { 
   for (int i=0;i<len;i++){ 
   list.add(jsonArray.get(i).toString());
} 
}

//Remove the element from arraylist

list.remove(position);
//Recreate JSON Array
JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray(list);
Edit: Using ArrayList will add "\" to the key and values. So, use 
 JSONArray itself

JSONArray list = new JSONArray();     
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonstring); 
int len = jsonArray.length();
if (jsonArray != null) { 
  for (int i=0;i<len;i++)
 { 
   //Excluding the item at position
    if (i != position) 
    {
        list.put(jsonArray.get(i));
    }
   } 
  }
```

Comment: HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
 org.apache.http.client.HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
 int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
if (status == 200) { HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
 String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
 JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(data);
 for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
JSONObject object = arr.getJSONObject(i);
 Apps actor = new Apps();
actor.setName(object.getString("prodType"));  
actorsList.add(actor); } return true;} }  return false; }

Comment: i tried above code it works, but i want to remove 'other type' in retrieved list from json.

Answer (score 0):

Before preparing `list`, create a data class

```
class Response{
 private void prodType;
 private void uid;
  //getters and setters
}
```

While adding each response object to List verify it its type is `other type` then ignore it